# JavaScript function expression and function declaration, am I right in my understanding?

Tags: javascript

Am I right in my understanding of this code. We call the function with an anonymous function. It firstly console logs the function ( as in the function structure, it does not run the function. It then runs the function when it comes across `a()`;

Is this correct?

```
var runIt = function(a) {
    console.log(a);
    a();
};

runIt(function({
    var b = " Now";
    console.log("Running" + b); 
});
```

Comment: Yes that is correct. A function call consists of a reference to a function followed by a parenthesized argument list.

Comment: `runIt(function({` -- Ehm, what's that supposed to be?

Comment: @Pointy - one of us is not reading that correctly because I don't see the 2nd part of that working at all.

Comment: `runIt(function({` should be `runIt(function(){` otherwise it will fail

Comment: @Archer oh right, yes the syntax is incorrect in the call to `runIt()`. But my take on what was being asked is that in the OP's actual test code that wasn't a problem.

Answer (score 1):

> We call the function with an anonymous function. It firstly console logs the function (as in: the function structure), it does not run the function. It then runs the function when it comes across `a()`.
>
> Is this correct?

Yes.

> JavaScript function expression and function declaration, am I right in my understanding?

No. This code has nothing to do with [function expressions vs function declarations](https://stackoverflow.com/q/336859/1048572).